# useEffect not rerendering

Tags: reactjs, frontend, use-effect

Ok I am new to using react useEffect hook and am confusing why I am having this issue. I use this code to fetch from Firebase API and I put it into an array called tempDoc :

```js
const tempDoc = []
useEffect(() => {
  var docRef = db.collection("campaigns");
  docRef.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        tempDoc.push({
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data()
        })
        setCampaigns(tempDoc)
      });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
}, []);
```

In the console it returns with the array of objects I want. I map over the array to display cards. For example let's say my array has 3 objects. Sometimes when the component renders, only 1 card displays but I can see that in my console, all 3 objects are in my array. Sometimes all 3 render but then when I go to a new page and return to main screen, only 1 card is showing. Very confused.

[image: Array showing 3 objects but main screen only displays 1]

There must be something happening with how the component renders. I am new to useEffect so I am not sure.

Comment: The `useEffect` hook runs *after* the component has rendered, and in fact, doesn't have much of anything to do with rendering a component at all. Can you update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) component code example? Other things can affect what is rendered. Where are you console logging the data?

Comment: Add the code that you tried to use to render the cards.

Comment: You seem to be running `setCampaigns(tempDoc)` inside `querySnapshot.forEach` cycle. You should only run it once, after that cycle.

Answer (score 1):

## Issues

If I had to guess I would say you have 2 issues:

1. `tempDoc` isn't part of react state, it's reset each render cycle
2. State updates are being enqueued in a loop, but don't update from previous state. When several state updates are enqueued within a single render cycle that don't update from the previous state they sequentially update from the same state from the previous render cycle.

## Solution

Use a functional state update to correctly enqueue each new doc. There is likely no need for the `tempDoc` array, you can just enqueue the doc data as it is processed.

```
useEffect(() => {
  var docRef = db.collection("campaigns");
  docRef.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        setCampaigns(campaigns => [
          ...campaigns, // <-- shallow copy previous state
          { // <-- add new doc element
            id: doc.id,
            ...doc.data(),
          }
        ]);
      });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
}, []);
```

You can alternatively just map the query snapshot first and use a single state update. (Thanks @ΔO'deltazero')

```
useEffect(() => {
  var docRef = db.collection("campaigns");
  docRef.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
      setCampaigns(querySnapshot.map(doc => ({
        id: doc.id,
        ...doc.data(),
      })));
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
}, []);
```

Comment: This is still running `setCampaigns` multiple times inside a `forEach`...

Comment: @ΔO'deltazero' This is fine when using functional state updates.

Comment: doesn't it cause multiple re-renders while cycling thru?

Comment: @ΔO'deltazero' No, all enqueued state updates from a render cycle are all asynchronously batch processed *between* render cycles and returned for the *next* render. If the looping is asynchronous then it is possible they are enqueued in different render cycles (but any queued *in the same* cycle will update & rerender once).

Comment: I see. So it makes a few redundant promises, but they are all resolved in other before render. Good to know

Answer (score 1):

Issues are described perfectly [here by Drew Reese](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65117126/3290062). My proposed solution is:

```js
const [ campaigns, setCampaigns ] = useState([]) // I suppose you already have this line

useEffect(() => {
  db.collection("campaigns").get()
    .then(querySnapshot =>
      setCampaings(querySnapshot.map(doc => ({
        id: doc.id,
        ...doc.data()
      })))
    )
    .catch(error => 
      console.log("Error getting documents: ", error)
    )
}, [])
```